# Quel est le sens de « … ma courte vue : j'aurais dû la fixer toujours plus près de moi » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

À la fin du livre *Du contrat social* de Rousseau, le dernier paragraphe contient:

> Après avoir posé les vrais principes du droit politique et tâché de fonder l’État sur sa base, il resterait à l'appuyer par ses relations externes ; ce qui comprendrait le droit des gens, le commerce, le droit de la guerre et les conquêtes, le droit public, les ligues, les négociations, les traités, etc. **Mais tout cela forme un nouvel objet trop vaste pour ma courte vue : *j'aurais dû la fixer toujours plus près de moi.***
>
> <sub>Rousseau, du Contrat Social, Livre IV chapitre 9</sub>

Ici je ne comprends pas bien la dernière phrase que j'ai mise en gras, spécifiquement la partie en italique.

Il me semble qu'il parle de sa courte vue, disant qu'il connaît les principes de base au sujet du droit politique, mais qu'il y en a plus pour comprendre et faire un bon état dont il ne connaît pas très bien. Et en réfléchissant, il dit qu'il aurait dû mieux faire attention à ces autres choses pour pouvoir les discuter plus en détails.

Les nuances des verbes m'échappent toujours ; ce qui me pose le vrai problème est le verbe *fixer* avec le complément d'objet direct *la*. Ici *fixer* veut-il dire *approfondir* ou quelque chose de similaire? Et le pronom *la*: cet objet direct me semble faire référence à *un nouvel objet*; ou bien, fait-il référence à *ma courte vue* ?

C'est toujours ambigu. Pourriez-vous m'aider à comprendre ce paragraphe ?

---

At the end of the book *The Social Contract* by Rousseau, the last paragraph is written:

> Après avoir posé les vrais principes du droit politique et tâché de fonder l’État sur sa base, il resterait à l'appuyer par ses relations externes ; ce qui comprendrait le droit des gens, le commerce, le droit de la guerre et les conquêtes, le droit public, les ligues, les négociations, les traités, etc. **Mais tout cela forme un nouvel objet trop vaste pour ma courte vue : *j'aurais dû la fixer toujours plus près de moi.***
>
> <sub>Rousseau, du Contrat Social, Livre IV chapitre 9</sub>

I don't understand what the last sentence that I bolded means, specifically the part in italics.

It seems that he's talking about his short-sightedness, saying that he knows fairly well the basic principles of political rights, but there's more to understand a state and create it that he doesn't know about. And, in reflecting, he says that he should have paid more attention to these other things so that he could discuss them in more detail (in his book).

The nuances of verbs still confuse me; the verb *fixer* with the direct object complement *la* is still causing my problems. Does *fixer* mean here *approfondir* or something similar? And the pronoun *la*: the direct object seems to reference *un nouvel objet*; or, does it reference *ma courte vue*?

It's still ambiguous - can you help me to understand the paragraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...   . Mais tout cela forme un nouvel objet trop vaste pour ma courte vue...

Tous les sujets évoqués forment un vaste sujet de réflexion pour l'auteur, qui ne *voit* pas aussi loin, dont la pensée ne peut parcourir de si vastes étendues d'études.

> ... j'aurais dû la fixer toujours plus près de moi.

Donc s'il ne peut apercevoir avec discernements des sujets aussi vastes, sa vue doit être fixée beaucoup près de lui : son terrain d'observation doit être proche de ses préoccupations habituelles

Lorsque l'on est concentré sur un sujet d'étude, l'attention et la vue sont fixées pour que l'observation et l'analyse soient optimales, ainsi elles ne peuvent pas dériver vers d'autres centres d'intérêts (sinon elles ne seraient pas 'fixées').

Answer (score 2):

Mais tout cela forme un nouvel objet trop vaste pour ma courte vue : j'aurais dû la fixer toujours plus près de moi.

But all of this is a new object [of study] that is too vast [to be studied] given my nearsightedness: Fixer un objet means to look at an object. Fixer [du regard]=to stare at, to focus on versus fixer un objet sur le mur, attach or fix

Literally: I should have gazed on this object closer to myself. That boils down to focus, which is also suggested by fixer.
Translation: **I should have focused on it [this object of study] or looked at it even more closely**

.
In older English: I should have gazed upon it at an even closer distance to myself.